# CRA not creating a react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to create a new react-typescript project as per the official [installation guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation). Getting this message during installation

"The react-scripts version you're using is not compatible with the --template option."

And it's creating a javascript react project instead of typescript.

I  also executed `$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and `$ npx clear-npx-cache` before creating react project.

My environment details are:

- npm: 6.14.17 (installed with snap)
- node: 14.19.3 (installed with snap)
- npx: 5.0.1

[image: error image]

**Edit:**

Here is the response of npm list --location=global

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^17.0.0, required by @mui/styles@5.9.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.0.0, required by react-driftjs@1.2.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.6.0, required by react-meta-tags@1.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0, required by react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@^16.0.0, required by react-driftjs@1.2.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@^16.6.0, required by react-meta-tags@1.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>= 2.7, required by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
npm ERR! extraneous: eslint@8.19.0 /media/umar/EDUCATION/Development/CanadaInnovates/centre-website/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/node_modules/eslint
npm ERR! extraneous: @babel/core@7.18.6 /media/umar/EDUCATION/Development/CanadaInnovates/centre-website/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/@babel/core
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5, required by eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9, required by eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.21.0
```

Comment: Can you post the response from npm list --location=global? . Also I had this happen once and a computer restart did fix the issue. For me it seemed the cache clear didn't take effect on my global list till after a restart

Comment: Thats a really unexpected result from that... does this work? if you have yarn have you tried using that to make the project?  yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript